# Android: Pass complex data structures through activities or services

Tags: android

Hi I want to pass  complex data structures from my Service class to Activity class.

I create class Serializable :

```
        class SaveMe implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        static final int test = 1234;

        private int user;

        private String name;

        private double score;


        public SaveMe() {}
    }
```

And I put it in Bundle

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("serializable", new SaveMe());
```

HOW can I send this information to Activity class ?

I try with this code :

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(INTENT_MAP);     
mapIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

And than I want to send to BroadcastReciver using:

```
 sendBroadcast(mapIntent);
```

But I receive force error!

Should I use BroadcastReceiver to pass this data structure to my activity?

How to send to another activity?

Thanks

Comment: Please reconsider your approach. http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/08/decoupled-activities.html

Comment: Whenever you report a "force error", you need to supply a stack trace or logcat log of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can store any data required globally by extending the Application class and including a getter to return the existing SaveMe stored there. You can access this from your activity with

```
private MyApplication application;

@Override
   public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ........
   this.application = (MyApplication) this.getApplication();
                ......
}

// elsewhere in your code
SaveMe mySaveMe = application.getSaveMe();
```

This article explains very clearly how to do this: http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746 You can ignore the stuff about the AsyncTask (although I'm sure you will find a need for that at some point) and just concentrate on the part about extending the application class.

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to basically steal the idea of the R class. You have a final class that you can reference from anywhere. I'm not sure if this is a good idea or not. Not many people try this